# How can I use scanf and if with strings? (Very basic)

Tags: c, string, scanf

I just had my first class in C programing at college and I did this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char answer='x';
    printf("Should the crocodile eat the man? y/n ");
    scanf("%s",&answer);
    printf("%s",& answer);
    if(answer == 'y')
        {printf("the man is dead");}
    if(answer == 'n')
        {printf("the man still alive ");}
}
```

How can I do the same with strings instead of single characters?

I have tried many things but nothing works.

Comment: reading a string (minimum 2 chars because of the 0 terminator) into one char is never going to work...

Comment: Please go ask your instructor.. anyways the answer is you will have to use array...

Answer (score 4):

In C, a *string* is a sequence of character values followed by a zero-valued terminator.  The string `"hello"` is represented by the sequence `{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0}`.

Strings are *stored* as arrays of `char` - the array must be large enough to hold the entire string *plus* the 0 terminator, so to store the string `"hello"`, you need an array of `char` that's *at least* 6 elements long.

It's important to remember that an array of `char` doesn't *have* to contain a string - you can use it to store character data that's not meant to be interpreted as a string.  You can also store more than one string to an array, like so:

```
/**
 * Array size is determined by number of elements in the initializer
 */
char strs[] = {'T','h','i','s',0,'i','s',0,'a',0','t','e','s','t',0};
```

After this, `strs` will contain 4 strings: `"This"`, `"is"`, `"a"`, `"test"`.

So, to store the *strings* `"y"` or `"n"`, you need an array of `char` that's *at least* 2 elements wide.

```
char answer[2];
```

To read strings with `scanf`, you use the `%s` conversion specifier:

```
scanf( "%s", answer );
```

`%s` tells `scanf` to skip over any leading whitespace, then read a *sequence* of non-whitespace characters and store them to the `answer` array.  A 0 terminator will automatically be appended to the array, making it a string.

In this case, you don't need to use the `&` operator on `answer`; under most circumstances, an expression of type "array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", so the expression `answer` "decays" from type `char [2]` to type `char *`.

To be safe, you should specify a maximum field width so that you don't read more characters than the target array is sized to hold:

```
scanf( "%1s", answer );
```

Since we have to reserve an element for the 0 terminator, the field width specifier should be at least 1 less than the size of the target array.  Since our target array is sized to hold 2 elements, the field width specifier pretty much has to be 1.

To compare strings, use the `strcmp` or `strncmp` library functions:

```
if ( strcmp( answer, "y" ) == 0 )
{
  // process "y" answer
}
```

Yes, `strcmp` returns 0 on a match.

You could also do a comparison against individual elements in the array:

```
if ( answer[0] == 'y' )
{
  // process "y" answer
}
```

**Remember**

If you want to read a *single* character from the input stream and store it to a *single* character object with `scanf`, you would use the `%c` conversion specifier:

```
char answer;             // single character, not an array
scanf( " %c", &answer ); // use & operator to obtain pointer, blank skips
                         // leading whitespace
```

If you want to read a *sequence* of non-whitespace characters from the input stream and store them to an *array* of `char` with `scanf`, you would use the `%s` conversion specifier:

```
char answer[2];          // array of character
scanf( "%1s", answer );  // do not use & operator to obtain pointer, array
                         // expressions are converted to pointer expressions
                         // automatically in this case.
```

Comment: Good on you John -- everybody needs a hand every now and then.

Comment: In the spirit of the basic nature of the question, it might be worth mention that `scanf()` automatically adds the `\0` terminator to strings read with the `%s` conversion specifier.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a buffer to store the string:

```
char answer[50]; // change 50 to the maximum length of an answer + 1
scanf("%s", answer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes but you need to pass it a buffer for the string and use strcmp instead of == for comparison.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char answer[16];
  printf("Should the crocodile eat the man? yes/no ");
  scanf("%15s", answer);
  printf("%s", answer);
  if (strncmp(answer, "yes", 16) == 0) {
    printf("the man is dead\n");
  } else if (strncmp(answer, "no", 16) == 0) {
    printf("the man still alive\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't need (const char *) typecast when you are calling strcmp() function.  It is also safer to use strncmp() rather than strcmp().

Comment: `scanf("%16s", answer);` --> `scanf("%15s", answer);`  15 in the "width", max number of characters to scan and save. `answer` needs 1 more for the null character.

Comment: `strncmp()` has little advantage over `strnmp()` here - if any.  If anything, checking the return value of `scanf()` like `if (scanf("%16s", answer) == 1) ...` is more important as that lets code know `scanf()` was successful or not.

Comment: Yes.  In this case strncmp() or strcmp() don't matter.